# Is the way to set handlelength for particular handle, not for all?

Tags: matplotlib, legend, handle, legend-properties

In my legend the width of handles is different, for more clarity look at this example:

```
----- Sin(x)
...   Cos(x)
____  Tan(x)
```

If I set handlelength it's applied for all of them and there is no way to fit them to one width, so can I set handlelength parameter for particular handle for adjusting this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to control the handle-length (though not using that parameter) and setting it to the maximum value/length in the legend (which sets the legend size). This approach directly modifies the line object in the legend.

```
LEGEND = ax.legend()
LLINES = LEGEND.get_lines()

MAX = max([max(X) for X in [L.get_xdata() for L in LLINES]])

for L in LLINES:
    plt.setp(L,xdata=np.array([L.get_xdata()[0],MAX]))
```

---

First, you extract the lines from the legend, using `get_lines()`. From these objects, you can extract the `x` values using `get_xdata()`. This is combined here into a single line finding the maximum `x` value from all the legend entries.
Once that maximum, `MAX`, has been obtained, you can loop through all the line objects in the legend and set the maximum `x` value to the extracted `MAX`. This will make all lines identically long.

---

Here's an example. It first manipulates one legend line to be longer (the legend does not resize, so this can only be taken so far, and is just to show an example here). Next, it extracts the new maximum and sets all lengths accordingly.

```
from math import pi as pi
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0.0,2.0*pi,101)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

LABEL = ['Sin(x)', 'Cos(x)', 'Tan(x)']

LINE = [[],[],[]]

LINE[0] = ax.plot(x,np.sin(x),label=LABEL[0])
LINE[1] = ax.plot(x,np.cos(x),label=LABEL[1])
LINE[2] = ax.plot(x,np.tan(x),label=LABEL[2])

ax.set_ylim([-1.0,1.0])

LEGEND = ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

This is the plot with the original legend:

[image: original legend]

Now, one can reset the first line length to a longer value, e.g.:

```
LLINES = LEGEND.get_lines()

plt.setp(LLINES[0],xdata=np.array([LLINES[0].get_xdata()[0],\
                                   LLINES[0].get_xdata()[1]*1.25]))

plt.show()
```

Resulting in this legend:

[image: longer single entry]

And finally, the above method to retrieve the longest line and apply it to all legend lines:

```
MAX = max([max(X) for X in [L.get_xdata() for L in LLINES]])

for L in LLINES:
    plt.setp(L,xdata=np.array([L.get_xdata()[0],MAX]))

plt.show()
```

Resulting in all lines having the same - now increased - length:

[image: all long]